# My program does not respond when two subprocess read from stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I have a C program that need some control information during its runtime. These information will be passed by my python program. I first test this, it works fine.

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess

cpro = ['./a_pass','2','8','7']        #2,8,7 are some parameters for init
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cpro,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
#p2 = subprocess.Popen(cpro,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

f1 = open('bdt.100','r')               #control information
commands = f1.read()

out1 = p1.communicate(commands)[0]     #get the c program output
#out2 = p2.communicate(commands)[0]

print out1
print '--------------'
#print out2
```

The problem is when I open the comments. I try to test if these information in stdin could be read by two process. But, my python program does not respond when I execute it. It just hang there. I guess the reason is two subprocess fight for reading stdin. How can I control them to work harmoniously?

Bst Regards.

**UPDATE**

I change my code to this, and it works:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(passOne,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
out1 = p1.communicate(commands)[0]

p2 = subprocess.Popen(failOne,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
out2 = p2.communicate(commands)[0]
```

I try to say something, but I just can feel something about what happened. So, I just put how do I fix the problem in my code without more analysis. Forgive me.

Comment: I don't think that's your problem - [`Popen.communicate()` waits until the program finishes](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) - so your programs are run one after another, not at the same time. My guess is the second process simply isn't terminating for some reason.

Comment: It's also worth noting you should use [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files - it's more readable and properly closes the file for sure (even on exceptions).

Comment: @Lattyware But I run the same C program with the same init parameters and control information. Why should they lead to different result? I am wondering that after subprocess1 read the stdin, what's the stdin looks like when subprocess2 come to read?

Comment: That largely depends on what the process you are running does. Have you tried using another process, that you know will work (say `ls`) and seeing if that has any problems?

Comment: @Lattyware replace subprocess 2 to `ls` make it works. Ah..confused.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the process you are running then, it looks like the error is there.

Comment: @Lattyware Actually, I'm doing The minimizing delta debugging algorithm which I need to run a correct program and a wrong program, they both need the same control information. I try to let subprocess1 run the correct and subprocess2 run the wrong one. Then pass a control string to stdin letting subprocesses read, But my program has no respond either. BTW. If I run them independently, each of them works fine(have respond).

Comment: @Lattyware I post a new edit where I put the changed code.

Comment: Next time you can also collect the standard error of your subprocess and print this. Could provide helpful insights :)